# Quarkus Panache multiple dependent parameters

Tags: java, database, hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have simple, versioned entities with some other, irrelevant fields and would like to select a list of them with dependent parameters. While the entity is not a PanacheEntity, my corresponding repo is a PanacheRepositoryBase.

Specifically the entity looks like this

```
@Table(name = "DUMMY_ENTITY")
@Entity
public class DummyEntity {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private UUID id;
  @Column(name = "VERSION", nullable = true)
  private Integer version;
}
```

Assuming I have 6 entities A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3 (where A or B is the ID and 1,2,3 is the version), how can I select A2 and B3 in a single statement? If I query (simplified representation) using

```
WHERE ANY(id, (A,B)) and ANY(version, (2,3))
```

Then I would get A2, A3, B2 and B3. Is there a way to pass multiple dependent parameters?